# Constraint preferredLayoutAttributes width

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewlayout

I work on a custom subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` with fixed columns and vertically growing items similar to Trello. Each item is basically a view that contains a few vertically stacked labels.

Currently what I observe is that `shouldInvalidateLayout(forPreferredLayoutAttributes:)` is being called with the computed by auto layout size but the size is rather `fittingSize`.

I wonder if there is any way to constraint the `preferredLayoutAttributes` width since I have fixed width columns, and let it calculate the height for me?

```
override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forPreferredLayoutAttributes preferredAttributes: NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes, withOriginalAttributes originalAttributes: NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> Bool {
  if preferredAttributes.size != originalAttributes.size {
    return true
  }
  return false
}

override func invalidationContext(forPreferredLayoutAttributes preferredAttributes: NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes, withOriginalAttributes originalAttributes: NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> NSCollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext {
  let invalidationContext = super.invalidationContext(
    forPreferredLayoutAttributes: preferredAttributes, 
    withOriginalAttributes: originalAttributes
  ) as! WeekViewInvalidationContext

  // save computed attributes to apply them later during invalidateLayout
  invalidationContext.updatedPreferredLayoutAttributes = preferredAttributes

  return invalidationContext
}
```

Comment: `UICollectionViewLayout` and macOS?

Comment: @Willeke thats NSCollectionViewLayout on macOS

Comment: I actually gave up and fixed the width in constraints for “cells” but truly wonder if I could make it managed by layout